# Shell script and sed commands

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script where I am executing a SQL query like so -

```
query=$(cat <<all
SELECT
    provider_rendering_npi
INTO table
FROM service sl
WHERE bucket = 'bucket'
AND month_id >= (SELECT month FROM annual);
all
)

sql=$(echo $query | sed -e "s/bucket/$bucket_name/g ; s/table/$directory/g")

psql -h server -U user db -c "$sql"
```

Based on a condition, I would like to modify the `query` variable. For example, if the `$bucket_name` contains `no_inp`, I would like to modify `query` to be

```
query=$(cat <<all
SELECT
    provider_rendering_npi
INTO table
FROM service sl
WHERE bucket = 'bucket'
AND month_id >= (SELECT month FROM annual)
AND st_info = 'no_inp';
all
)
```

Is there a way to do this without duplicating code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function parameterized on the optional query expression (`expr`):

```
query() {
  local expr=$1
  local newline=$'\n';
  cat <<EOF
SELECT
    provider_rendering_npi
INTO table
FROM service sl
WHERE bucket = 'bucket'
AND month_id >= (SELECT month FROM annual)${expr:+$newline}$1
EOF
}

query
query "AND st_info = 'no_inp'"
```

It's usually easier to assemble things from parts instead patching a whole.

Comment: How do I echo the contents of the `cat` to make sure if `query("AND st_info = 'no_inp'")` is being passed correctly?

Comment: Similar to what you had: psql -h server -U user db -c "$(query "AND st_info = 'no_inp'")".   If you only have these two queries move the psql command into the query function.